# USB AOA ADK in C issue

Tags: android, c, android-source, libusb

I'm creating a firmware on a Silabs EFM32LG330F128 microcontroller in C to communicate in USB using the protocol AOA (Android Open Accessory) with Android smartphones.

I'm using the Silabs USB library, adapted to switch in AOA protocol and communicate with the smartphone.  [-> AOA protocol](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/custom)

I done a first version which works with most of smartphones. But with a particular one (a Lenovo Moto Z2), it doesnt work !  At the last step, the setting of the device configuration to a value of 1 answers an error code : USB_STATUS_EP_STALLED

The issue doesnt come from the smartphone, it works with another library ([libusb](https://libusb.info/) ) on RPI3. 
By the way, with this library, the last step (set the device configuration) is not mandatory : the smartphone switch and start to AOA.

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks a lot, in advance
Benjamin